# Laravel 5.1 View not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, homestead

this seems to be an issue that pops up every now and then within Laravel. I was writing a CRUD controller with a view to go with it, however upon testing I got the `InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [bookingcrud.index] not found` error. Here is my code:

routes.php:

```
Route::resource('bookingcrud', 'BookingsCrudController');
```

BookingsCrudController.php

```
use uasc\Http\Requests;
use uasc\Http\Requests\CrudCreateRequest;
use uasc\Http\Requests\CrudUpdateRequest;
use uasc\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Auth;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BookingsCrudController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        if (!Auth::check() || Auth::user()->authority < 1) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        $raw = "select * from bookings";
        $bookings = DB::select($raw);
        $paginatedBookings = new Paginator($bookings, 1);

        return view('bookingcrud.index')->with('bookings', $paginatedBookings);
    }
}
```

And a view located in `~/laravel/resources/views/bookingcrud/index.blade.php`
No matter what is in this view file whether its markup from a working view or just the word "cheese" i will always get:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 140:
View [bookingcrud.index] not found.
```

I tested the same view in a known working controller and got the same error however I tested a known working view on the same CRUD controller and it worked. I have also tried changing the directory of the view and renaming it but i'll get the same error with the "View [bookingcrud.index]" changing appropriately. I made sure the permissions of the file and directories were full for testing.

Since first getting the error I have upgraded to 5.1.1 from 5.0.26 (which is the version the error originated on for me) and ran composer update. Also from looking at threads with the same error I have also ran artisan config:clear

I am developing on Windows 8.1 with Homestead 2.0.17 deployed with Virtual Box.

Any help would much appriciated at this point it is doing my head in.

Comment: Make sure the right permissions are set and that if requests are case-sensitive that the file matches exactly. [link](http://laravel.io/forum/06-14-2014-invalidargumentexception-view-schoolsindex-not-found-please-help-its-urgent)

Comment: As mentioned in the question the file and directory permissions are full (777 or -rwxrwxrwx etc.) and the file paths are all lowercase with no spaces

Comment: Try using `php artisan serve` in the console and navigate to http://localhost:8000/ and see if you can get that page. If you can, it's going to be an issue with your Homestead setup. Otherwise we can narrow it down to something in your code.

Comment: Yeah I have tried this also still received the same error when i navigated to http://localhost:8000/bookingcrud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I had spelt blade incorrectly, took a second pair of eyes to notice it though.

```
$ ls resources/views/crud/booking/
crud.balde.php  index.balde.php
```

Was definitely a lesson to always double check the small things when debugging.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14):

Please use terminal

```
homestead ssh > Press Enter
vagrant@homestead cd /Path_of_Your_Project/
vagrant@homestead:~/Path_of_Your_project php artisan cache:clear
vagrant@homestead:~/Path_of_Your_project php artisan config:cache
```

Sorry about my English

Answer (score 4):

For someone who don't have SSH Access, There are two ways to solve this problem.

If you don't have any plugin of default Laravel package,
First, Just remove the **bootstrap/cache/config.php** to solved the file,

OR

If you have any plugin of default Laravel package,
Change all related path mentioned **bootstrap/cache/config.php** into the exact path which allocated the laravel project.

Comment: You have made my day, i was facing the same issue. The site was working fine on my localhost, but it displayed "invalidargumentexception" about view not found. I tried many solution but your one worked fine.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Linux is case sensitive!

I had something like this:

```
return view('MyView', $data);
```

And it was working on my environment (Mac OS), but not on the deployment server (Ubuntu)!