# Change root folder name

Tags: laravel

My Laravel project folder was "laravel" so i changed to "testsite", but now i cant access the site.

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [pages.home] not found.

ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 109: file_put_contents(C:\Users\Zen\Google Drive\xampp\laravel\storage\framework/sessions/4d5b7c28f025c192658893a77c2d6bdb60b33d48): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Full error can be found here:

[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/9PyEvaE4)

Its visible in the paste that is something related with sessions from the old folder "laravel".

Using Xampp with virtualhosts, restarted Xampp, cleared browser cache, it didint solved the issue.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried running this command `php artisan clear-compiled`?

Comment: Didint work. Added the following folders "storage/framework/sessions" in the old "laravel" folder, the session error is gone, but it still looks for views in the old "laravel" folder. For some reason Laravel is fetching files in the old "laravel" folder, i need to find a way to set to the new "testsite" folder. `composer update` Updated correctly the dependencies, but still didint solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved, has described here: [Laravel 5.1 View not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802687/laravel-5-1-view-not-found)

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an inconsistent path, take a look of how you're setting the slashes:

```
xampp\laravel\storage\framework/sessions/
```

Besides that, make sure that the `framework/session` folder exists

Also check that pages.home hierarchy exists in your views folder:

```
View [pages.home] not found
```

Comment: I only changed the folder name to _testsite_ and pointed to _testsite_ folder in XAMPP vhosts. But the folder `framework/session` exists and it contains several files. The pages.home exists (but trying another page, like _/login_ causes the same issue). Regarding the inconsistent path, i´m not setting the path, nether less the path should be `\xampp\testsite\..` not `\xampp\laravel\..`. Also tried to clear artisan cache, dump-load..nothing works